# Running a forEach loop for $$ not completing the Promise

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm trying to fetch the value of radio button using forEach array iteration. Even I mentioned the Promise statements [Promise, Promise.all, Promise.resolve], I gets results which shows still promise is not completed.

// First code with Promise.

```
let radioButton = await $$('.radioButton')
let radioValue = radioButton.map(async (element) => {
    await Promise(await element.getValue())
});
console.log("Radio value==>"+radioValue)
```

Output: **Radio value==>[object Promise],[object Promise],[object Promise]**

Comment: Do you actually need any Promise in such a case? Among other things, "await" has no effect on `$$` as the result is not promise-like.

Comment: Tried without Promise and just with await statement [ await element.getValue() ]. Dint work. Trying with promise also has same effect.   Output is always **Radio value==>[object Promise],[object Promise],[object Promise]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was giving Promise.all() statement inside map(). I should have given it outside map()... Statement like await Promise.all(array.map()). Now it waits for all promise to finish inside for-loop. and gives output as expected.

```
let radioButton = await $$('.radioButton')

console.log('type(radioButton)->'+typeof(radioButton))
let radioValue = await Promise.all(radioButton.map(async element => {
    return await element.getValue()
}));
console.log("Radio value==>"+radioValue)
```

**o/p: Radio value==>radio1,radio2,radio3**